# multi-thread / multiprocess with postgres and csv in python

Tags: python, postgresql, multithreading

I have a data that contains around 80 mil data, i have split it in 8 csvs so each has a 10 mil.
now what i want to do is that get that data from the csv file and insert them into a postgres database.
the problem of course is time.
at this point i tried using the multiprocessing and multithreading as well.
with multiprocessing it wont even run, pycharm gives me a SIGKILL.
im trying not to use pandas, because when i tried to use read_csv() i get same SIGKILL.

I tried to run each line as thread and insert them like that, tried to run into 8 thread which gave me best result so far (7 minutes).
my question here is if i can make my multithreading code more efficient?

```
def insert_rows(rows, connection):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for row in rows:
            new_data = ["None" if char == "" else char for char in row]
            new_data = ["2001-06-20" if "00" in char and (new_data.index(char) == 4 or new_data.index(char) == 5)
                            else char for char in new_data]
            cursor.execute(
                    f"INSERT INTO user_anime_table ({','.join(columns)}) " \
                    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", new_data
            )
            print("inserted a row")
    connection.commit()
    print("connection commited")


def read_csv(file_path):

    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host=DB_HOST,
        port=DB_PORT,
        database=DB_NAME,
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASSWORD
    )
    print("connection happened")
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        rows = list(csv_reader)
        print("turned rows to list")

    row_count = 10041165
    chunk_size = row_count // 500
    threads = []

    for i in range(thread_count):
            start_index = i * chunk_size
            end_index = start_index + chunk_size if i < thread_count - 1 else row_count
            chunk = rows[start_index:end_index]

            thread = Thread(target=insert_rows, args=(chunk, connection,))
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
            print("appended a thread")

    for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
            print("joined the threads")

    connection.close()
    print("connection close")


file_path = CSV_PATH
thread_count = 20

read_csv(file_path)
```

this code uses 20 threads with took 17 minutes, so by my understaing using less threads works better.

```
def insert_rows(row, connection):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
                    f"INSERT INTO user_anime_table ({','.join(columns)}) " \
                    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", row
            )
            print("inserted a row")
    connection.commit()


def read_csv(file_path):

    connection = psycopg2.connect(
        host=DB_HOST,
        port=DB_PORT,
        database=DB_NAME,
        user=DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASSWORD
    )
    print("connection happened")
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
        rows = list(csv_reader)


    for row in rows:
            thread = Thread(target=insert_rows, args=(rows, connection,))
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)


    for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

    connection.close()


file_path = CSV_PATH

read_csv(file_path)
```

this is code for each thread for each row.
i would like to have some opinions about what should I use or if there is any way to make this code better

Comment: Set logs into the code to check the bottleneck, e.g. check the elapsed time of every function calls.

Comment: Why don't you use copy? That is so much faster: https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html

Comment: because with copy i had a problem of user, as i remember. i had to move the files to tmp for them to write + i want to retrieve those files from sql and filter so i thought might as well use threads while inserting too

Comment: When your code can read the csv file, and it can because your code is already doing this, you can use copy.

Comment: okay thanks but do you have any suggestion with retrieving that much data from postgres?

Comment: also copy gives me this error -> AttributeError: 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' object has no attribute 'copy'